# Converting to epoch time-stamp adding hours offset

Tags: c#, datetime, epoch

I have date time in a string as "20160127003500".
What I need to do is convert this to Unix time-stamp adding hours to it.

I want to add hours offset as "1" or "2" or "24".

Can anyone please guide me in right direction.

***Regards***

Comment: Just convert it to a regular DateTime and AddHours. There's plenty of guides on converting time all over SO.

Comment: That string looks like it's in `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format, which you can use with `DateTime.ParseExact`.  However, you'll also need to know whether to interpret it as local time, UTC time, or time in some other time zone - because Unix time is UTC based.  Without knowing the source time zone, you can't do it.

Comment: Please also clarify what exactly you mean by "I want to add hours offset".

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for replying the original timezone is CET, here is what the full string has "20160129205500 +0100". By hours offset I meant incrementing or subtracting number of hours from this time by passing an integer value.

Comment: Don't do that.  Just use `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`.  I'm on my phone, but I'll post an example when I get back to a PC unless someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, parse the entire string (including the offset you mentioned in the question comments) to a `DateTimeOffset`:

```
using System.Globalization;

string s = "20160129205500 +0100";
string format = "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz";
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then, there are a few different ways to get a Unix timestamp.  Note that by the pure definition of a "Unix timestamp", the result would be in terms of *seconds*, though many languages these days use a higher precision (such as *milliseconds* used in JavaScript).

If you are targeting .NET 4.6 or higher, simply use the built-in methods:

```
// pick one for the desired precision:
long timestamp = dto.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
long timestamp = dto.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

If you are targeting an earlier version of .NET, then compute it yourself:

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

// pick one for the desired precision:
long timestamp = (long) dto.UtcDateTime.Subtract(epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
long timestamp = (long) dto.UtcDateTime.Subtract(epoch).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: excellent! That is exactly what I needed. Thanks a million. Marked as answer.